# ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH on ajax request

Tags: nginx

I am running a server under nginx (Ubuntu). I am attempting to make a AJAX request using jQuery to a C++ service (deployed with ngrest):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/wordly/echo",
    type: "GET",
    data: {inputStrings, ["dog"]},
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            var msg = '';
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                msg = jqXHR.readyState;
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                msg = 'Time out error.';
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
            } else {
                msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
            }
            alert(msg);
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('.greeting-id').append(data.result);
        },
        timeout: 30000
    });
});
```

The service is expected to run for about a couple of seconds before returning a result. By making it log to a file I confirmed that it is started and working but its execution is stopped at some point, but the C++ code of the service does not have problems.

When calling in Chrome I can see that the ajax error's `jqXHR.status` and `jqXHR.readyState` are both 0. Additionaly in the console I can see the following error message:
`GET http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/wordly/echo?inputStrings=[%22dog%22] net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH` (X's representing the IP address of my server).

What can be causing the abrupt interruption of my service's execution? I have tested my setup with very simple and fast services and it seems to work, am I correct to assume the problem lies in some nginx setting?

Comment: You're right, it would be better to remove most, edited.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having a similar issue on a PHP project with Nginx whenever an ajax call is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being that my response was more than 4kb, making it less than that solved the problem for me